# Display content in View Glossary

Tags: 7, views

I've created a glossary page with the view module and for now i can display some nodes by clicking on their first letter. What i want is to display all nodes before the click and then be able to sort them with a letter or a filter. Can't find any options to do this in the view.

I'd also like to know if i can modify this page directly by programming it, i don't find the file who contain the glossary page.

Comment: are you using view_glossary module?

Comment: No just view who provide a glossary view by default

Comment: If I am reading this right, it is all about your display. You should be able to select Content instead of fields or whatever you have. You can tpl different view modes and add them to the ct if the default does not look good. A screen shot of what you have may help.

Comment: if you have it set as fields, you could use group option in field settings. It would display each item under a group title given by the letter ( all starting with N under a title of N, etc) - you would need to include the first letter as a field, or use php to extract it in order to assign the value to the group setting. You could then simply include the list above as a global header with anchors to the group titles

Comment: My prolem was that the nodes didn't display when the page was loading. I had my letter filter like : D(1) L(1) M(1) S(1) T(1) and had to click to display the content. I figured out that part it was about the contextual filters. Now i have another issue, i put some filters criteria (filter by langage, type etc..) and when i select a letter i can apply those filters to the nodes who has that first letter but i can't reinitialize the filters for displaying all the nodes like it was in the first place, it only reinitialize the nodes for the letter i choose before. (Tell me if i'm not clear enough)